# SBCL: CONTINUE restart absent during COMPILE? (really was:absent in HANDLER-CASE)

Tags: error-handling, common-lisp, sbcl

In using `swig` to wrap a C++ library, I had been attempting to bypass a compile-time `error` of an un`eql` constant being redefined … in this case, to an `equal` but un`eql` string literal.

Strangely, in SLIME I was able to simply invoke the `CONTINUE` restart and bypass this particular error. However, when I try to wrap it with a `handler-case` and build it via either `compile-file` or `slime-compile-file` or via `buildapp`, the `CONTINUE` restart seems to be missing. `(format t "Restarts: ~{~% • ~A~%   ~:*~S~}" (compute-restarts))` concurs.
Just to be paranoid, I've tried:

```
   (continue)
   (invoke-restart 'continue)
   (invoke-restart (find-restart 'cl::continue))
```

and a few variations.

`(unless (continue) (warn "Can't continue"))` is also, strangely, not warning me, but the compilation doesn't finish the file, either.

Due to some more awful cases of C++ polymorphism that I want to convert to keyword arguments, I'm continuing onwards with a copied and edited version of the `swig` generated code, but I'm curious why the restart would be absent and whether I could have done something (some hard-to-locate dynamic setting, perhaps) that would bypass it.

*Edit:* Lest it be helpful, one variaton has been:

```
(handler-case
  (compile-file "path/to/swig-made-this-mess")
  ;; contains (defconstant foo "string")

  #+sbcl
  (SB-EXT:DEFCONSTANT-UNEQL (condition)
    (let ((name (SB-EXT:DEFCONSTANT-UNEQL-NAME condition))
          (before (SB-EXT:DEFCONSTANT-UNEQL-OLD-VALUE condition))
          (after (SB-EXT:DEFCONSTANT-UNEQL-NEW-VALUE condition)))
      (if (equal before after)
          (progn
            (warn "Redefining constant to un-EQL but EQUAL value~%~S ← ~S"
                  name after)
            (unless (continue)
              (warn "Unable to CONTINUE~%~%Restarts:~{~% • ~A~%     ~:*~S~}"
                    (compute-restarts))
              (signal condition)))
          (progn
            (warn "Redefining constant to un-EQUAL value:~%~S ←~%before: ~S~%after: ~S"
                  name before after)
            (signal condition))))))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HANDLER-CASE isn't the right tool. By the time its clauses are invoked, the stack has already unwound. HANDLER-BIND's clauses are invoked in the context where the error was signaled before the stack unwinds, so use HANDLER-BIND instead.

Comment: d'oh. Thanks, I knew this had to be a (:facepalm:) kind of thing, but spent an hour diagnosing the wrong problem.